# How to revert a pull request commit on GitHub

Tags: github, git-revert

I am trying to revert my latest commit on GitHub. All the information I have looked through says that there should be a revert button in the pull request but I do not see it, and cannot find it.

Is there anyway to do this on GitHub? Or could I do it terminal with a few rebase commands?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/reverting-a-pull-request/

Comment: Is this pull request commit a merge commit?

Comment: pull request commit @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming this pull request merge is a commit merge (what I would expect), then you may try the following from the Git bash:

```
git checkout your_branch
git revert <hash of merge commit> -m 1
git push origin your_branch
```

This solution assumes that you want to revert back to the branch into which the pull request merge was made.  If you want to follow the incoming branch, then use `-m 2` instead.

To find the SHA-1 hash of the merge commit, you may use `git log`, and then copy over the hash from the first commit, which should appear at the top.

Note that nuking the merge commit and then doing a force push is generally a bad idea here.  The reason it is bad is because your branch is published on GitHub.  This means that rewriting the history of that branch could cause problems for anyone besides you who happens to be sharing this branch.

Comment: And the hash I should use is the hash of the commit I would like to go back to?

Comment: No, use the hash of the merge commit which you wish to revert.  _Don't_ do what you are suggesting please.

Answer (score 0):

In android studio click `version control` tab in the bottom. Then click `log`

Then your all the commits will be visible. Then right click on relvent commit and revert it.

Then commit changes and push again.

Answer (score -1):

Get the hash of the commit in which you want to revert back. Then do:

```
git checkout 54722c31619b0662b379923d0be4b8f8f1f125c9
```

The long number you are seeing is the hash of that particular commit in which you want to revert back.
Then force push into the branch you want to revert back.

```
git push origin <your_branch_name> --force
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding :)

Comment: Should I make this hash the commit I want to remove, or the one I want to go back to?

Comment: This is a generally bad suggestion, because you are suggesting rewriting the history of a public branch via a force push.

Comment: Make the commit you want to go back. @TimBiegeleisen Can you please elaborate.

Comment: How would you suggest I do this Tim? I do not have the option for a revert button.